# Expresiones regulares java swing

Tags: java, regex, java-swing

Estoy intentando aplicar una validación de entrada para los textos de un usuario. La idea es que me pueda servir para un JTextField como para otro tipo de componente Swing con JTextArea o similar.

Por un lado tengo:

```
public class LimitChars
    extends PlainDocument {

public enum TipoEntrada {
    ENTERO, DECIMAL, NONE, EMAIL, ALFA
}
private final TipoEntrada tpEntrada;

public LimitChars(TipoEntrada tpEntrada) {
    this.tpEntrada = tpEntrada;
}

@Override
public void insertString(int offs, String str, AttributeSet a)
        throws BadLocationException {
    if (str == null) {
        return;
    }
    String regex = "";
    switch (tpEntrada) {
        case DECIMAL:
    //                regex = "^[0-9]{1,3}(.[0-9]{1,3})?$";
            regex = "\\d*\\.\\d{2}";
            break;
        case ENTERO:
            regex = "^\\d+$";
            break;
        case NONE:
            regex = "^[\\w\\d\\s\\t\\n]*$/i";
            break;
        case EMAIL:
            regex = "^[\\w\\d-]{3,}[@][\\w\\d-]{3,}[\\.][\\w\\d]{2,}$/i";
            break;
        case ALFA:
            regex = "^[\\w\\d\\sáéíóúäëïöüñ@-\\t\\n]*$/i";
            break;
    }
    Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(str);
    if (matcher.matches()) {
        super.insertString(offs, str, a);
    }
    //        str = str.replaceAll(regex, "");
}
```

}

Y en la parte Swing, palabra es un JTextField:

```
palabra.setDocument(new LimitChars(LimitChars.TipoEntrada.DECIMAL));
```

Después de varias pruebas, el resultado es que, o bien me permite escribir un número que sobrepasa los límites de cifras, sin posibilidad de escribir el punto decimal, y el otro resultado que he obtenido es que no me permite escribir en absoluto.

No doy con el problema, y creo que la expresión está correcta.

Alguna idea?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El problema con `JTextField.setDocument` es que solo podrá controlar qué caracteres se pueden ingresar, pero no una "máscara" como está tratando de hacer. Con solo esto, no podrá controlar la **cantidad de caracteres** en cada parte de la cadena, por lo que este `[0-9]{1,3}` es inútil.

Con esto en mente, puede crear expresiones regulares mucho más simples, solo para aceptar caracteres específicos, ejemplo para `DECIMAL = "[0-9\\.]*"`, y luego crear un **listener** para "enmascarar" lo que se escribe después de cada carácter.

Aquí hay un [ejemplo de máscara](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/FormattedTextFieldDemoProject/src/components/FormattedTextFieldDemo.java), del Oracle, pero están usando un `PropertyChangeListener`